# In Django Admin interface, can we have autocomplete lookup without a foreign key relationship?

Tags: django, django-admin

Is there a way in the django admin to define an auto-complete field that looks up values from another model with which it doesn't have any foreign-key/many-to-many relationship?
I have tried `django-grappelli`, and `django-ajax-selects`, but it seems both expect me to define the foreign-key on which I want the look-up.

Answer (score 0):

Try use autocomplete from jquery:
[jquery autocomplete](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/)

In jquery autocomplete you must prepare list with appriopriate values:

- the first possible way (I always use this in standard templates) is to pass queryset to context and prepare list in javascript in template like that:

  var some_list=[{% for element in some_list_from_context %}{"label":"{{element.name}}"}{% if not forloop.last %},{% endif %}{% endfor %}];

  The thing is, that I don`t know the way to extend admin template and pass variable to context.
- The second possibility is try add javascript file to admin:

  class Media:
      js = ("path/to/js/file",)

  and in that file make ajax call to some method, which deliver list with objects